# This is an OLD game that I still enjoy

Tags: riddle, video-games

This is a small riddle I thought of myself about my still favorite game to play. Let me know what you think about it (did you like it, was it too simple).

> I've slain dragons not once but twice,
> As many times have I seen the morning end but not rise.
> By The Way, While gathering sand,
> I once found a hand.
> It's easy to get a pet to which I do not attach,
> for as time goes on death is what I catch.
> They say skill is what I lack,
> Thus an inferno is what I gave back.
> There can only be one king,
> WOOT is not the answer but if you replace one letter this is who I
> would bring.

What is the name of the game I'm referring to?

Hint #1:

> The last sentence There can only be one king, WOOT... : this refers to the in game name of the person that is seen as the best player ever of this game.

Hint #2:

> It's an online game

EDIT:

Phrase 2 and 6 still need an answer.

Comment: Because the inferno and dragons it would make sense if soot was there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the answer

> Old school (classic) Runescape

I've slain dragons not once but twice,

> There was a dragon slayer quest in the game, recently they added a dragon slayer 2 quest to the game.

As many times have I seen the morning end but not rise.

> The quest Mourning's End Part I and II

By The Way, While gathering sand,

> You need to gather lots of sand to create glass. Especially in iron man mode. (In this mode you need to be self sufficient)

I once found a hand.

> Hand in the sand quest.

It's easy to get a pet to which I do not attach,
for as time goes on death is what I catch.

> The first and easiest pet to get is the black cat. You can sell it for death runes.

They say skill is what I lack,

Thus an inferno is what I gave back.

> The Inferno is one of the hardest challenges in the game, you need to prove your worth before you can start this challenge.

There can only be one king,

WOOT is not the answer but if you replace one letter this is who I would bring.

> WOOX is a top player of the game.

Comment: that would be the correct answer congratulations on solving the riddle ^^

Comment: Thanks but did I get part 2 correct?

Comment: Yes part 2 is now also correct, great job! hope you enjoyed it a bit solving :p.

Comment: Yeah, it was fun. I've only played it long ago, when it just started :)